# Ubuntu Flash only working on youtube

Tags: 14.04, flash

There are lots of question on this topic, but my problem is little bit weird. I don't know whether other people are facing same issue. I have ubuntu 14.04 freshly installed. I installed flash player, but flash videos/audios are only working for youtube and facebook. Other websites like 8tracks, gaana.com etc. Flash player is not working. My flash version 11.2.202.400

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the flash player you installed and install the following package in a terminal

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

This contains a flash plug-in for any browser exept Chrome/Chromium which has its own installed by default.

Answer (score 0):

If restricted-extras packages doesn't solve your problem on chromium (like me) please install **pepper flash player**.

```
sudo apt-get install pepperflashplugin-nonfree

sudo update-pepperflashplugin-nonfree --install
```

Pepper flash player solve your problem most probably.